# How to count those registered on a given datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to count all records created on a x date, but the table column is not of type `date`, it is `datetime`

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM dbo.Customers
WHERE (SELECT registered_date CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) FROM dbo.Customers)
```

I am trying to convert datetime column to date but I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'

Comment: If you get past the syntax of T-SQL, your next issue is likely to be that the subquery in the `where` clause is not a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery). It will either find row(s) or not, thus the `count` will return the number of non-null `id` values or not regardless of the `registered_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the subquery is for. Would this work:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM dbo.Customers
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, registered_date) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Edited to add the convert for registered_date.

Comment: Relevant https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you want your predicate to be *sargable*, I suspect you need something like

```
select count(*)
from dbo.Customers
where Registered_date >= convert(date, getdate()) 
      and Registered_date < convert(date, dateadd(day, 1, getdate()));
```